# Finding elements by class name inside a loop, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriver

I need to scrape in python a page that has some classes that are number like `class1, class2, class3, ... classN` and I would like to locate the text contained in all those classes.

I tried using `find_element()` function:

```
list = []
for i in range(N-1)
  list.append(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class" + str(i+1) ).text))
```

but unfortunately I get this error message:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".class1"}
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.68)
```

Is there any other way I could succeed in this scraping?

---

EDIT

This is the [page](https://www.flashscore.it/partita/YgxSmkBr/#/informazioni-partita/informazioni-partita) I would like to scrape and I would like to get the games won by both players per every set.

In the source code the classes are named `"smh__part  smh__home smh__part--" + str(i+1)` and respectively `"away"`

Comment: You need to post the relevant html? `but unfortunately this did not work` what does this mean, are you getting syntax error or what's the error?

Comment: I just edited the question with the error log message. I do not think there is anything more that could help in html code I need to scrape, however, if it may help you I'll post the source code

Comment: Please check if element present in iframe or it is opening in new window? without steps to reproduce the issue, it's hard to provide a solution.

Comment: Are you sure those elements having single class value? can you share at least HTML of some of those elements? Preferably the link to that page itself...

Comment: Edited the question with the link. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class_name` only accept single class name not multiple.
Instead use `css selector`. use python `format()` function

```
list = []
for i in range(N-1):
  list.append(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='smh__part  smh__home smh__part--{}']".format(i+1)).text)
```

---

OR `CLASS_NAME` with single class value

```
list = []
for i in range(N-1):
  list.append(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "smh__part--" + str(i+1) ).text)
```

Comment: This was simply great. Thank you very much! Can I ask you where could I find a documentation for handling strings with the format function?

Comment: It is python function `format` https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp